# storing metadata from the spotify api

Tags: spotify

I want to use the spotify api to create a webapp. Without going into too much detail about the project, I want to clear up whether it would be against the terms and conditions or not.

After reading the terms and conditions, i read this line under things NOT to do: "aggregate Metadata to create data bases, or any other compilations of Metadata".

I don't plan to do any automated requests, for example, hammering the service with different queries to build a database... I'm just wondering whether I can store results from users who have performed searches via my application to the api, so that I can build content from my database on other parts of the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a lawyer, so you'll need to have a lawyer confirm this (contracts, including ToS contracts, are important), but the general gist is that if you cache the results of user-generated requests to create features then you're ok. If you start caching stuff not generated by a user, you're in muddy water.

Good:

> Other users who searched for "Madonna" in MyAwesomeApp also searched for "Backstreet Boys"!

Bad:

> Here's a list of all the blue cover arts on Spotify: [list]

To generate the first example you can cache and work with searches explicitly done by users of your application. The second would require scraping all of the coverart in the service, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Hi, I had this doubt as well.

So, for example, a server cant save results obtained from the web api and must discard them after using them? But, if the users send the server their results its no problem? Just want to absolutely confirm because the terms of service are purposely vague in this regard.

Somewhat off-topic, but can these types of apps be sold in the mobile app stores? (iOS, android, etc) The terms dont state anything regarding commercial use of the web api.

Comment: You can save the results from the web API if the request was made to serve a user request - that is, if the user wants to search for "Madonna", you can save the results.