# Can I store and use the metadata provided by spotify?

Tags: spotify

I am not sure what Spotify means by not being able to store metadata to create a database. I saw another user ask a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387403/storing-metadata-from-the-spotify-api) but the answer was a bit vague.

We are planning on building a site that will showcase all songs offered by spotify, similar to a directory, and we will let the user search by artist, song title, album, and genre and let them play the song using Spotify's Play Button. Then we will also recommend songs to them based on songs from the same genre, artist, album, etc. is this something Spotify lets you do?

Comment: [May be worth looking at the terms of use.](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/terms-of-use-us/)  I'm not entirely sure that Spotify would allow that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Spotify lets users do that already — it's called the Spotify client ;-)

Seriously though — the answer is in the terms of use as Makoto points out. If you're at all unsure, find someone well versed in legalese to interpret it for you.

As I said in the answer you linked to, I'm not a lawyer. However, if you idea requires some sort of crawler to scrape stuff from Spotify's API, that's likely to be a no-go. If your idea only requires sending requests to Spotify's API based on stuff users type/click on in your website, you should be ok.